# Putting lawn mower into car trunk

Tags: car, hardware, moving

My grammy needs me to go mow her yard before the meanies at the HOA fine her for having disorderly yard. I need to help my grammy ASAP! There is a problem though, I'm unable to lift lawn mower by myself into my car trunk, and no one else is around to help me lift it!

How can I go about getting the lawn mower into my trunk? Bonus points for ways to take it out once I get to grammy's home.

[image]

Yes, same size as the car/trunk pictured.The question is about how to get it up there since I can't lift it by myself. The question is NOT about how to fit it in the trunk.. I already know it will fit in the trunk.

Comment: Is that a random picture included or one of your car? The type and size of your car does matter in questions like these.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When moving a cement mixer recently I used a small trailer, and self built ramp. The ramp consisted of two lengths of wood, 2"x4" (48 mm x 198 mm) and 5 ft (150 cm) length. Here is an image of how you could make the ramp:

[image: Two lengths of wood from the curb into the trunk of a car]

The trick to using lenghts of wood for a ramp, is to make sure that they doesn't break nor slip. Proper dimensioned planks ensure no breaking, but do take care when using the ramp. And here are some ideas to reduce the risk of slipping:

- **A**: Make a lip at the end of the wooden planks which goes down into the trunk
- **B**: Let the end of the planks stop against the curb, if possible
- **C**: In a pinch, you could temporarily take out two car mats, place one over the trunk edge to protect the trunk edge, and put another under the end of plank to increase the friction

When utilising the ramp, push the lawn mover unto the bottom part first and wiggle it a little to make sure the ramp is stable. Now simply push it into the car, possibly shifting grips to the lower end of the lawn mover handles when halfway up the ramp.

Let it gently go down into the trunk on the front wheels, and fasten it securely. Remember to pick up the planks, and stick into truck before driving off.

Comment: wow, a drawing too, very detailed. Something to add; you could have the blocks(A) at both ends, if the ramps will be against the curb. This will give the ramp a more gradual climb while bringing it more level with the curb.

Answer (score 10):

Use a ramp to push it into your trunk. You can take the ramp with you to unload at your grammy's home...

Comment: I don't have a ramp. But yea, that would totally work for putting it in the trunk if I did.

Comment: Every piece of strong flat wood is a potential ramp. A lawnmower doesn't weigh that much so many materials would be strong enough.

Comment: All you need for a ramp is two lengths of wood.

Answer (score 3):

Either a lever or a pulley allow you to move something heavy with reduced effort.  My first thought would be to find a tree with a sturdy branch that you can sling a good quality rope over.  You can then use the pulley effect of the tree branch to lift the mower out of the trunk.

Answer (score 2):

An engine hoist would probably work well, and some of the home use ones disassemble/fold for transport and storage. However they are fairly large so this does depend on the type of car and lawn mower you have. (SUV vs compact car? and push vs rider mower?)  This is only cost effective if you already have a hoist or can borrow one because they are similar in price to a lawn mower.

Other thought, have you tried borrowing a lawn mower from one of her neighbors? Return it with a full gas tank if you do!

Answer (score 2):

Easiest (and quickest) way (Grammy's waiting) is to back up to a curb, then use a box, half the height of the trunk and a small, flat piece of wood (Ply, 2 ft. by 2 ft.).

Simply back up to the curb, then place the box on the floor and use it like a large step. If needed, place the wood like a ramp, but with the top overlapping the top of the box. Tilt the mower back and push forward so the front wheels either go on top of the box, or the top of the plywood. Then, while pushing forward, see-saw the mower onto the top of the box. You can use the same process to get the mower up another level into the trunk. This process will take little effort.

Answer (score 1):

Get a box or crate (something that's about 1x1 ft at least) which is made of wood or other sturdy material.

Place the box next to the rear bumper of your car. Use the handle of the lawnmower to tilt the mower forward, so that the rear wheels are off the ground but front are still on the ground, and slide the box edge beneath the rear wheels.

Stabilizing the box with your foot (best if the box is on its side and your foot is in the open side), pull back on the handle to lever the front wheels up higher, and swivel the mower on the box to get the front mower wheels over the lip of the trunk.

Walk the front wheels of the mower into the trunk. Place the box in the car.

Reverse the procedure when you get to your grammy's house.

This method has you exerting a maximum of half the force required to lift the whole mower. Hopefully this is manageable for you.

Answer (score 1):

Do this every summer multiple times.

Using wood as ramp, is probably the only lifting alternative.

I purchased an electric mower with a cord, and it is much lighter than a gas engine solution.  Then you don't have to mix oil, gas, change spark plugs or etc.  Just get a 100' cord and your done.

Some cars have a back seat that goes down, and allows access to the trunk.
I put the back seat down, and then put the handle in first.

Then the trunk closes easily.

You should just buy a second lawn mower, and leave it at their house.  You only have to move it once, and the cost is trivial compare to carting it around.

Some stores offer delivery, if not order it online, and fedex, ups, or etc will gladly deliver it.